# Discord.py attach image from bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I making a bot that sends a random photo of Will Smith from a folder in my Downloads folder thats called `willy`. I dont have the random part implemented but I'm trying to have the bot send an image in the `willy` folder called `0aPw0J4.png`. I just want the script to be able to find the image and upload it. Currently the error is that python cant find the directory even though I tried to list the directory starting from my `C:` drive but that didnt work so I deleted it.

```css
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!_")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bots online')

@client.command()
async def will(ctx):
    await ctx.send('will')



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!_will'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="A photo of Will Smith", description="Here he is", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
        embed.set_image(url="https://discordapp.com/assets/e4923594e694a21542a489471ecffa50.svg")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await client.send_file(channel, "0aPw0J4.png", content="...", filename="...")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!willy'):
        file = discord.File("0aPw0J4.png", filename="0aPw0J4.png")
        await message.channel.send("0aPw0J4.png", file=file)


client.run('my bot token hidden')
```

I tried changing my default directory but that didnt work either.

Comment: Please share the full error message.

Comment: you have two functions defined that have the same name

Comment: @AlexanderCécile FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0aPw0J4.png'

Comment: @aws_apprentice is it the two bottom `client.event`s ?

Comment: yes, also have you tried providing the full path to the file?

Comment: can we send the image using the bot while typing the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's a working directory problem, always try to reference the file with an absolute path in cases like this. Use the `os` module to see if it can find the folder with the images:

```
import os
# it will print all files in that folder
print(os.listdir('folder path of the images'))

# it will print True of False if the file exists with this path
print(os.path.isfile('absolute path of the image'))
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'listdir' is what i get when I run it